# Possible error in given definition of uniform continuity of a function on a metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I have the following defitions

[image]

I don't really see a difference between the two definitions. Shouldn't the first one be with for all x and there exists \delta switched?

If there is no mistake, could someone please explain the difference?

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information not otherwise present in your post. [See here for an explanation of why this is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: The difference is that the first definition is "anchored" at $y$: it's about the behavior of $f$ near a *fixed* $y$.  The second is for all $x,y$; it's about the behavior of $f$ at any pair of close-enough points. Consider $f(x)=1/x$ on $(0,1). It is continuous at each point, but not uniformly continuous because you can always find two points that are as close as you specify, but whose images are very far apart.

Comment: I understand now thank you. I think that I missed the "is continuous at y" bit from the definition. Can you please post this as an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Please add the relevant information so that it does not rely on the image alone.